# Netbeans sysout autocomplete

Tags: netbeans

I've just started using netbeans 8.2 and when i type **sys** for `System.out.println()` i have an autocomplete of `System.out.println(className.methodName())` , i want this to be simply `System.out.println()`.

I've checked *options->keymap* but it doesn't seem to be there, where should i go to fix this ?
Thanks

Comment: try sop and then tab

Answer (score 1):

By default you have to type sout and then tab which will then be replaced with System.out.println("").

You can add your own abbreviation behaviour if you want. Just go to "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Editor" -> "Code Templates" -> "Java" and enter sys for your abbreviation and then enter 'System.out.println("")' in the "Expanded Text" field below.